# What's the difference between ulong and long while calculating the binary pattern of a value?

Tags: c#

Codes below allow user to input an integer and convert it into binaries. The input number is 
(1)parsed into long type and
(2)transformed into ulong type.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
class Program
{ 
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const int size = 64;
        ulong value;
        char bit;

        Console.WriteLine("Enter an integer");
        value = (ulong)long.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        ulong mask = 1UL << size - 1;
        for(int count = 0; count < size; count++)
        {
            bit = ((mask & value) != 0) ? '1' : '0';
            Console.Write(bit);
            mask >>= 1;
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
}
```

It works!
[image: input integer 42]

But if I don't transform the value into ulong, there is something wrong:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
class Program
{ 
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const int size = 64;
        long value;
        char bit;

        Console.WriteLine("Enter an integer");
        value = long.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        long mask = 1L << size - 1;
        for(int count = 0; count < size; count++)
        {
            bit = ((mask & value) != 0) ? '1' : '0';
            Console.Write(bit);
            mask >>= 1;
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

[image]
May someone tell me why?

Comment: Did you make any attempt whatsoever to debug your code? Did you step through, watching the variable values? Did you notice at any point a variable having a value different than what you expected? The answer to all of those questions should be "yes", and if so, then that point described in the last question is where you can find the answer to your question.

Comment: The following code will make this problem stand out from a mile away (and make most of your code redundant): `Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(mask,2))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In two's complement systems negative numbers are represented using bit patterns that have their most significant bit set to `1`. Therefore, when you make a signed `mask` by shifting `1` 63 times to the left, you get a negative number:

```
long mask = 1L << size - 1;
```

This is the key to understanding what happens next: right-shifting a negative number preserves its sign. In other words, if the most significant bit is `1`, then `1` is going to be shifted into the number at the top, not zero.

Your `mask` will go through this sequence as you shift it:

```
100000...000
110000...000
111000...000
111100...000
...
111111...100
111111...110
111111...111
```

That is why the condition `(mask & value) != 0` will become `true` when the train of ones reaches the highest set bit in the value, and would remain there until the end.